# How to scale out VMs in Azure Container Service Docker?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service

I created Docker(+swarm) with Azure Container Service template.

1 master and 1 agent created, but how can I scale out agent VMs? The template generates agent VMSS(scale sets) but not found to add more VMs in Portal UI.

Found [template documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview/) but it seems not handy.

Is there any way to do it only with a few clicks like Azure Worker Role?

Comment: I have not tried this. but shouldn't creating a scale set with say 2 VMs spin out couple of VMs ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [easier solution](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/change-the-instance-count-of-an-azure-vm-scale-set/) than @jluk suggested.

For CLI haters like me,

1. go to https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-scale-existing
2. Click "Deploy to Azure" button. It will open portal UI and show some textinput fields.
3. Input VMSS name and instance count to the fields, and Accept legal terms.
4. Click OK. wait till they all deployed.

Note that, if you change instance count `1` to `3`, three instances are initialized and you will see 1 running + 3 creating. Later, one is removed so three instances are running.

In case of docker, you have to download docker image to newly created instances and run one by one if you did not setup docker automation yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of today there is no way to scale a VMSS via Portal UI, you must use template rules or the Powershell/CLI. This is on the product roadmap though.

You can get setup with the CLI from the repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli)
I would encourage familiarity with the CLI anyways if you have to use a mix of Linux/Windows across scale sets or update scaling rules frequently.

Edit:

You are correct, the template quickstarts are a viable alternative.
Be mindful though if you provide a VM Sku in the template that is different than the existing VMSS, it will redeploy your current scale set to the new SKU provided in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can now scale Azure CLI and via the portal see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-scale (though at the time of writing this doesn't document scaling via the portal - got to your ACS cluster, select "Agents" under settings  and enter the desired number of agents in the appropriate field)